# Can I pull only certain files from another git repository?

Tags: git, branch, merge, git-branch

For instance, suppose I have Repository 1 and Repository 2.  Repository 1 has a file `/a/b/c/d`.  Would it be possible for me to import this file into Repository 2 as `/e/f/g/h`?

The reason being that I want to pull in changes from an experimental branch from a different git repository.  I tried merging everything together, but there were a ton of conflicts (of every kind).  Therefore, I doubt that I can merge the entire branch in, but I would like to try to bring in as much as I can.

Is there any way to do what I want to do, or am I just going to have to resort to copying files directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get files from the remote repository using `git archive`. You could then add and commit the files to your repository. This approach will not preserve history from his branch. See [git archive docs](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-archive.html) for details.

If you want to try to preserve parts of that experimental branch, you could `git fetch` his repository, and then `git rebase` his experimental branch onto your repository, editing or skipping commits with conflicts as appropriate. Once you have a cleaned up branch in your repository, you can merge that in. See [git rebase docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)

Answer (score 2):

There's no simple fix, but there is a really well written guide [here *(Move files from one repository to another, preserving git history)*](https://medium.com/@ayushya/move-directory-from-one-repository-to-another-preserving-git-history-d210fa049d4b) by *Ayushya Jaiswal* and I'll quote it in this post for archival purposes.

**tl;dr**: You're essentially re-basing a repo (safely) and extracting just the file(s) that you want. Then pulling the git history from your rebased repo into whatever repo you're currently working on.

**Notes before you get started**:
You'll need https://stackoverflow.com/a/56334887/929999 for this as well, if you want a specific file. I'll add a disclaimer below in the quoted guide where to add in this step.

Here's the quoted text from the article:

---

### Getting files ready to move from Repository A.

**Step 1**: Make a copy of repository A as the following steps make major changes to this copy which you should not push!

```
mkdir cloneA
cd cloneA
git clone --branch <branch> --origin origin --progress \
  -v <git repository A url>
# eg. git clone --branch master --origin origin --progress \
#   -v https://github.com/username/myproject.git
# (assuming myprojects is the repository you want to copy from)
```

**Step 2**: Go to that directory.

```
cd <git repository A directory>
#  eg. cd myproject
# Folder Path is ~/cloneA/myproject
```

**Step 3**: To avoid accidentally making any remote changes (eg. by pushing), delete the link to the original repository.

```
git remote rm origin
```

---

**This is the step to modify**, modify it by doing the `git filter-branch --prune-empty ... $FILES` step from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56334887/929999) instead, that will extrapolate only your desired files. The rest should be the same.

In your case, it would be something like this:

```
FILES='/a/b/c/d'
git filter-branch --prune-empty --index-filter "
                        git read-tree --empty
                        git reset \$GIT_COMMIT -- $FILES
                " \
        -- --all -- $FILES
```

<strike>**Step 4**: Go through your history and files, removing anything that is not in `FOLDER_TO_KEEP`. The result is the contents of `FOLDER_TO_KEEP` spewed out into the base of repository A.</strike>

```
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter <directory> -- --all
# eg. git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter subfolder1/subfolder2/FOLDER_TO_KEEP -- --all
```

**Step 5**: Clean the unwanted data.

```
git reset --hard
git gc --aggressive 
git prune
git clean -fd
```

**Step 6**: Move all the files and directories to a NEW_FOLDER which you want to push to repository B.

```
mkdir <base directory>
#eg mkdir NEW_FOLDER
mv * <base directory>
#eg mv * NEW_FOLDER
```

Alternatively, you can drag all the files and directory to the NEW_FOLDER using GUI.

**Step 7**: Add the changes and commit them.

```
git add .
git commit
```

### Merge the files into the new repository B.

**Step 1:** Make a copy of repository B if you don’t have one already.

```
mkdir cloneB
cd cloneB
git clone <git repository B url>
# eg. git clone 
https://github.com/username/newproject.git
```

**Step 2**: Go to that directory.

```
cd <git repository B directory>
#  eg. cd newproject
# Folder Path is ~/cloneB/newproject
```

**Step 3**: Create a remote connection to repository A as a branch in repository B.

```
git remote add repo-A <git repository A directory>
# (repo-A can be anything - it's just a random name)

# eg. git remote add repo-A ~/cloneA/myproject
```

**Step 4**: Pull files and history from this branch (containing only the directory you want to move) into repository B.

```
git pull repo-A master --allow-unrelated-histories
# This merges master from repository A into repository B
```

**Step 5**: Remove the remote connection to repository A.

```
git remote rm repo-A
```

**Step 6**: Finally, push the changes

```
git push
```

You can delete both the cloned repositories.
The files changes with history are now available online in repository B.

Comment: The FILES syntax isn't correct. If a, b, c, and d are separate files as the S at the end of FILES indicates, FILES must be a list of paths, relative to the repo root, separated by spaces. For example: `platformio.ini Marlin/Configuration.h Marlin/Configuration_adv.h`. I only tested this by retyping that list in place of `$FILES` in both places it occurs, but it should work if you save the space-separated list to the variable. Unrelated: for `git pull repo-A master --allow-unrelated-histories`, "master" must be the name of the existing branch in repo-A you want to use, which may differ.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to copy the file directly. Git deals with whole repositories, not single files within them.

I suppose you could set Repository 2 up as a remote repository, fetch (*not* pull) its branches, then use `git checkout` to grab a file out of that branch, but that solution could be messy.

Answer (score 0):

A really simple process is described at [Extracting a file or a folder from a git repository with full git history](https://www.pixelite.co.nz/article/extracting-file-folder-from-git-repository-with-full-git-history/):

1. Create a patch file

   ```
   cd ~/repository/path
   git log --pretty=email --patch-with-stat --reverse --full-index --binary -- path/to/file_or_folder > /tmp/patch
   ```
2. Optionally replace paths if required
3. Apply commits to new repository

   ```
   cd ~/another_repository/path
   git am < /tmp/patch
   ```