# How to filter particular files for the release from a git repository?

Tags: git, release-management

Please, it is possible to create an independent branch in development git repository which would contain only specific file(s) for a release without regression tests e.g.? How?

For example, I want to create this branch containing only the perl command and push it to the git repository in `/usr/local/bin`. The merge with the master branch there would be the deployment with a (change and release) history track but without the history of tests development etc.

I read [Git: Transfer Specific Files and Histories From One Repository to Another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851896/git-transfer-specific-files-and-histories-from-one-repository-to-another) but I don't want to create a whole new repo with `filter-branch`. I would prefer to create only a release branch with the whole history but stripped to the particular file. Let say a combination of `git log --file` and `git filter-branch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Release management should be separate from development.

- development is managed in your version control tool (here git), with additional files (like your test files)
- release is a process which takes a package (in your case, all files except the test ones) and deploy them (here simple copy to /usr/local/bin)

You shouldn't need to tweak the history of your repo to represent the "package" (set of files to be deployed in a target environment).
You should push your repo to a **[bare repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24115534/6309)** on the server (the target environment), and let a [post-receive hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11323004/6309) take care of the deployment (the copy of the right files to `/usr/local/bin`)

Comment: Thank you. And compilation + building is the process that creates the package. Should the packages be also versioned in some git repo or simply archived? Are there some arguments against git repo in /usr/local/bin (like [etckeeper](https://joeyh.name/code/etckeeper/)). So it is possible to quickly revert deploy. Or is better to force install previous package (or remove new and install previous)? Could you please add more links about Best build/release/deploy practices with git? See [A successful Git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

Comment: "Should the packages be also versioned in some git repo or simply archived?" Not archived in a *source* control system, but rather in an artifact referential (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/25236654/6309. More links at http://stackoverflow.com/a/23777122/6309). The successful Git branching model is about development workflow, not release management.

Answer (score 1):

I found a *technical* solution to my original question, but VonC answer about release management is more correct.

```
set -e
git filter-branch --prune-empty --index-filter '
  git ls-tree -z -r --name-only --full-tree $GIT_COMMIT \
  | grep -v "^\(some_file_regexp\|another_file_regexp\)$" \
  | xargs -0 -r git rm -q --cached -r --ignore-unmatch'
git checkout -b release
git checkout master
git reset --hard refs/original/refs/heads/master
rm -r .git/refs/original
```

Is there a more elegant technical solution?

Comment: If you insist on tweaking the history, then your solution seems good. +1. I have added some links in my comments below about the separation of dev and release management.