# git: copy/move range of commits to separate repository

Tags: git

I created a new feature branch and added a file there. Every commit after creating that branch only targets this file.
Now I want to move those commits to a new repository that is just for this new file.
How do I achieve that? I tried to add the old repository as remote branch to the new repository and cherry-pick all commits but I also get older commit messages from before the feature branch and from other files and I lose the original commit dates.

## So this is what I need:

- copy/move a range of commits from one repo to another
- only the commits of that file beginning from creating that file to today (there are no other files involved in between, but before creating the old feature branch)
- keep original authors and commit dates

## What I've also tried:

```
# git rebase --onto develop oldRepo/feature/issue#14 c7bc952
```

where c7bc952 is the current HEAD.

## What I got:

```
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...

# git status
HEAD detached from 4ae31a1
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Comment: Looks like something around here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375528/how-to-extract-one-file-with-commit-history-from-a-git-repo-with-index-filter

Comment: Hmm... looks like unix shell is involved, but I'm on Windows.

Comment: "git bash" shell is usually available in Windows dist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Major surgery like this is best done by directly constructing the new history. I like to do work like this in a scratch clone:

```
git clone -s . $TMPDIR/wip         # scratch clone
cd !$
```

Now to rewrite all of history to include only commits affecting that file, and only that file from those commits:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter '
                        git read-tree --empty
                        git reset $GIT_COMMIT -- that/file
                ' \
        -- --all -- that/file
```

If you want just one branch, use e.g. `master` instead of `--all` above.

Now you can push the rewritten branches anywhere you want.  Remember that "origin" in this repo is the repo you cloned from.

---

As a quick recap:

- a working repository comes in four parts: object db, refs, index, worktree.   The `HEAD` ref conventionally identifies the commit that produced the current index and worktree; `git commit` uses it as the new commit's first parent,  `git checkout` switches it out to the new branch, and so on.
- the index is just a list: pathname, content id, metadata about inflight ops.  Git status, for instance, checks the `HEAD` ref to see what was committed at a path, the index to see what you last added or checked out there, and the worktree to find any unstaged aka unadded aka untracked aka unindexed content.
- the refs are just thumbs into the object db.

So, `git read-tree` is what loads the index from the object db (and, if you ask it to, the worktree). It's the fundamental operation underlying much of what you do with git.

---

So filter-branch invokes the filters you supply on everything rev-list produces from your args (the stuff after the first `--`).  Here, I'm supplying  `--all -- that/file`, so rev-list supplies every commit that touches `that/file`.  When you supply an index filter, filter-branch loads the index from the commit, sets `GIT_COMMIT`, runs your filter, and rewrites the commit using the resulting index state.

Here, `git read-tree --empty; git reset $GIT_COMMIT -- that/file` empties the index and then loads only the `that/file` entry from the current commit.  Lather, rinse, repeat.

Comment: It works fine. I have a rough idea how it works, but is there any explanation available how this works? I tried to read the docs for filter-branch and read-tree but this is too high for me at the moment. But I want to learn!

Answer (score 1):

I answer my question because this is the first solution I found, maybe it is helpful for others:

```
git rebase hash_of_parent_of_first-commit hash_of_last_commit --onto develop --committer-date-is-author-date
```

This rebases all commits from my current feature branch to my before empty develop branch.