# How to move a few selected files and commits to a new repository?

Tags: git, version-control

I worked in a project some time ago that required me to develop a separated tool to make this project easier, and everything is in the same git repository.

I would like to select only a few commits that include changes to certain files (for example `tool.c`, `tool.h`) and add them to a new repository so that I can continue to improev this tool and have the history of changes.

Is that possible and if yes, how do I do it?

Comment: Perhaps a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7375528/5784831)?

Comment: Looks likely, OP, do you want the entire history for the selected files, or is there some need to specify "just these commits, ignore all those others that thouch these files"?

Comment: @jthill, my intention is to select all commits that change the selected files, ignoring changes to other files if these commits happen to do it.

Comment: @Christoph, thanks, I tried to search but didn't see this question, will read and see if it fits my case.

Comment: I've marked my question as duplicate because I've found exactly what I want following links from the suggestion above, thanks you both.