# How to pull a particular file to the server from github

Tags: git, github

I have a repo in github I have pushed lot of files to my github, but I want to pull only couple of files to the server. How do I do it. I just googled but could not figure out anything.

Comment: Take a look at this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104441/can-i-pull-only-certain-files-from-another-git-repository

Comment: Thanks @davids but I am looking for something different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think this is possible with git to pull only one/few of the files from a commit. But I think downloading few file is possible with github as mentioned in this [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604663/github-download-single-files)